# Angular OpenId Connect : first rendering occurs before token is ready

Tags: angular, openid-connect

I am using Angular 10 and angular-auth-oidc-client (https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client).

I want the user to be redirected to the authentication server if not logged (no login button).

I did this :

```
// component : 

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {
  }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    return this.authService.checkAuthAndLogin();
  }
}


// service : 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  async checkAuthAndLogin(): Promise<void> {
    await this.oidcSecurityService.checkAuth().subscribe((auth) => {
      if (!auth) {
        this.login();
      }
      console.log('is authenticated', auth);
    });
  }

}

// http client interceptor to send tokens to my backend : 

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService
  ) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.oidcSecurityService.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

It is working but the first rendering always fails, I have to refresh the page to get it work. It sends an empty token to my backend server on the first load.

I have found a workaround that is to wait 500 ms in the init method, but it seems very dirty :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {
  }

  loggedIn = false;

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    return this.authService.checkAuthAndLogin().then(() => {
      
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500)).then(() => {
        this.loggedIn = true;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And in my app component template :

```
 <div *ngIf="loggedIn">
  [...]
 </div>
```

It behaves like if the oidcSecurityService.checkAuth() resolves to early, while the token is not ready yet.

Is there a cleaner solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the async/await in the service (edit : and async in gnInit), I kept the `isLogged` boolean with ng-if (still don"t know what I need to do that), and now it is working :

```
checkAuthAndLogin(): Observable<void> {
    return this.oidcSecurityService.checkAuth().pipe(map((auth) => {
      if (!auth) {
        this.login();
      }
      console.log('is authenticated', auth);
    }));
  }

// componenent : 
ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    return this.authService.checkAuthAndLogin().toPromise().then(() => {
      this.loggedIn = true;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to use `return`  in onInit.  I think it is important to understand when to fetch the token and how to display the route on authentication. You should recheck the flow.

Comment: Async is only used when you are using await.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not returning the proper results:

```
 checkAuthAndLogin(): Promise<string> {
 return new Promise((res, rej) => {
   this.oidcSecurityService.checkAuth().subscribe((auth) => { // don't user await with observables
      if (!auth) {
        this.login();
        rej('Auth is failed')
      }
      console.log('is authenticated', auth);
      if (auth) res('authenticated');
    });
 })
    
  }
```

It seems like when you call `checkAuthAndLogin`, you are not returning anything. I am not sure what your auth service is doing all together. But you need to wait for the authentication token to receive and then make it login true and resolve the promise or you can use Behaviour subjects to make it happen.

Comment: It did not work either, but I think you're right that I should not use async/await here